# Paypal - IOS SDK - Business account / sole trader

Tags: ios, paypal

We are creating an IOS app and we'd like to use your IOS SDK for payments on behalf of our clients clients.  We have implemented your SDK into our app and all works great and we are really happy with it but we just have a few things we'd like to clarify if possible?

Our app is for personal trainers and we want to be able to offer them the facility of charging their clients for services in app.  So the Paypal account would need to be setup in the personal trainers name, they would need to create a client id and then enter their paypal email and account ID information into the apps CMS - which would then be fed securely into the app which is used by their clients to order services.

The SDK requires a client ID and registered email - which we were able to create in our business account via a rest api.  Our question is whether this process would still work if the Personal Trainer registered their Paypal account as a sole trader - or would they need a business account to create a client ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to be Business account.

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/admin/manage-apps/#upgrade-your-paypal-account-as-necessary

Comment: fair enough - thats a blow!  Cheers for your help @Mido

Answer (score 0):

Just to understand your question is the same as ours.
We have an app for a client. 
We want to integrate payment for them in the app.
With Paypal iOS SDK the parameters initWithClientId and receiverEmail need to be obtained by our client from paypal by registering for a developer api? 
Why would a business register for a developer api?

payerId is our client's customers paypal/emailid?

With MPL this was not needed?
Thanks.